# Is there any equivalent for gluScaleImage function?

Tags: opengl, glew, glu, oglplus

I am trying to load a texture with non-power-of-two (NPOT) sizes in my application which uses [OGLPlus](http://oglplus.org/) library. So, I use images::Image to load an image as a texture. When I call `Context::Bound` function to set the texture, it throws an exception. When the size of the input image is POT, it works fine.

I checked the source code of OGLPlus and it seems that it uses `glTexImage2D` function. I know that I can use `gluScaleImage` to scale my input image, but it is dated and I want to avoid it. Is there any functions in newer libraries like GLEW or OGLPLUS with the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

It has been 13 years (OpenGL 2.0) since the restriction of power-of-two on texture sizes was lifted. Just load the texture with `glTexImage` and, if needed, generate the mipmaps with `glGenerateMipmap`.

**EDIT:** If you truly want to scale the image prior to uploading to an OpenGL texture, I can recommend [stb_image_resize.h](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_resize.h) — a one-file public domain library that does that for you.

Comment: @Hamed: The idea of scaling the textures to power-of-two is as dated as the `gluScaleImage`. `glTexImage2D` already supports non-power-of-two textures. If it doesn't work, there must be a problem somewhere else, maybe in your code, maybe in OGLPlus (never used it, and I don't even understand why do you need this junk). Please show the relevant parts of your code, what exception do you get, and from where it originates.